# Keeping absolute div with text on image

Tags: html, css

Alright so the problem is quite simple, I am trying to make this system where my text will be over my image but the problem is I cant do it since my div is absolute (and since I made some stuff with it I cant change it to relative since it will be a major overhaul if I do)

```
#box_1 {
    position: absolute;
}

#box_1 img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#box_1 h1 {
    position: absolute;
}

<div id="box_1" class="test_div"><img src="img/scripting.jpg" /><h1>Documentation</h1></div>
```

So any suggestions? I really have to keep the text on top of the image and keep the DIV at position absolute

EDIT: Example here 
https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/textoverimageexample.jpg

Comment: on top of means, over the image like this ? https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/textoverimageexample.jpg

Comment: Yes correct, on top of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `z-index` and text to be `position:absolute`

```css
#box_1 {
    position: absolute;
}

#box_1 img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#box_1 h1 {
    position: absolute;
}
#text
{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:black;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="box_1" class="test_div"><img src="http://www.ew.com/sites/default/files/styles/tout_image_612x380/public/1455655770/homer.jpg?itok=TOtuVefM" /><h1>Documentation</h1>
 <p id="text">
        Hello World! Hello Galaxy !
    </p></div>
```